# Unicode is not displaying when reading foreign words from text file

Tags: java, android, unicode

I am trying to create foreign dictionary, but when I try to load dictionary data from txt file. It represents like this ������������. Here is method I use to read that file:

```
   private WordList(Context context) throws IOException {
    mWordList = new ArrayList<>();
    AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
    InputStream is;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder=new StringBuilder("");
    is = am.open("dat.txt");
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    while (bufferedReader.readLine()!=null){
    stringBuilder.append(bufferedReader.readLine());
        Log.d("String",stringBuilder.toString());
        StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(stringBuilder.toString(),",;'");
        Word word = new Word();
        StringBuilder def = new StringBuilder();
      /*  for (int i=0; i<stringTokenizer.countTokens();i++){
           if(i==0){
               word.setWrodName(stringTokenizer.nextToken());
            if (i==1){
               def.append(stringTokenizer.nextToken());
            }
               if (i==2){
                   def.append(",  ");
                   def.append(stringTokenizer.nextToken());
           }
               if (i==3){
                   def.append(",  ");
                   def.append(stringTokenizer.nextToken());
               }
               word.setWordDefinition(def.toString());
           }
            def.delete(0,def.length());

        }*/
        stringBuilder.delete(0,def.length());
        mWordList.add(word);

    }
    is.close();
    Log.d("String",stringBuilder.toString());

}
```

In row Recycle View it shows stroke with symbols and numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try to passing the encoding?

```
// Change encoding to "UTF-8" or whatever you want.
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, encoding));
```

or try this way

```
Reader in = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("file"), "UTF-8"));
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check database encoding type utf8, utf16, latin.............
2. Made changes on UI accordingly. Like <%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>  in html or jsp
3. Check character encoding of dat.txt.